# Volume of solid by Spherical

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

Trouble setting up the integrals for this problem.

Find the volume of the solid bounded by $x^2 + y^2 = 1, z = 0$, $z = 6$, $y\geq 1/2$. Use integration with Spherical coordinates. (Hint: Use two triple integrals and tangent inverse)

Using Mathematica, the answer is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k1D2.png) and the solid looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm7dJ.png).

The integral that I have setup, which doesn't evaluate to the correct answer, is [image: integral]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $z=6$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$, we get $\rho\cos\phi=6, \rho\sin\phi\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}$; so $\tan\phi\sin\theta=\frac{1}{12}$ gives

$\tan\phi=\frac{1}{12}\csc\theta$ and $\phi=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{12}\csc\theta\right)$.

When $z=6$ and $r=1$, we get $\rho\cos\phi=6, \rho\sin\phi=1$ so $\tan\phi=\frac{1}{6}$ and $\phi=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{6}$.

When $z=6, \rho=6\sec\phi$; and when $y=\frac{1}{2}, \rho\sin\phi\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}\implies \rho=\frac{1}{2}\csc\phi\csc\theta$.

This gives $\displaystyle V=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{5\pi}{6}}\int_{\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{12}\csc\theta}^{\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{6}}\int_{\frac{1}{2}\csc\phi\csc\theta}^{6\sec\phi}\rho^2\sin\phi \;d\rho d\phi d\theta\;+$

$\displaystyle\hspace{1.1 in}\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{5\pi}{6}}\int_{\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{2}\csc\phi\csc\theta}^{\csc\phi}\rho^2\sin\phi \;d\rho d\phi d\theta$.

---

(I believe the first integral gives $\frac{2\pi}{3}-\sqrt{3}+\frac{1}{8}\ln(7+4\sqrt{3})$ and

the second integral gives $\hspace{.4 in}\frac{4\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{8}\ln(7+4\sqrt{3})$, for a sum of $2\pi-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$.)

Comment: With these integrals, I am not getting $2\pi-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$. I also think you intended to use $6sec\phi$ instead of $6sec\theta$ in the first integral. But either way, using that integral, I get something else entirely. I double checked with Mathematica using `NIntegrate[
  rho^2 * Sin[phi], {theta, Pi/6, 5 Pi/6}, {phi, 
   ArcTan[Csc[theta]/12], ArcTan[1/6]}, {rho, Csc[phi] Csc[phi]/2, 
   6 Sec[phi]}] + 
 NIntegrate[
  rho^2 * Sin[phi], {theta, Pi/6, 5 Pi/6}, {phi, ArcTan[1/6], 
   Pi/2}, {rho, Csc[phi] Csc[theta]/2, Csc[phi]}]`, resulting in $-223.31$.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks! I accidentally entered it in Mathematica incorrectly. The correct entry is `NIntegrate[
  rho^2*Sin[phi], {theta, Pi/6, 5 Pi/6}, {phi, ArcTan[Csc[theta]/12], 
   ArcTan[1/6]}, {rho, Csc[phi] Csc[theta]/2, 6 Sec[phi]}] + 
 NIntegrate[
  rho^2*Sin[phi], {theta, Pi/6, 5 Pi/6}, {phi, ArcTan[1/6], 
   Pi/2}, {rho, Csc[phi] Csc[theta]/2, Csc[phi]}]`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; I did mean to have $6\sec\phi$, but typed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is the volume of a slice of a cylinder: such volume is just six times the area of the region:
$$ \left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\leq 1,y\geq\frac{1}{2}\right\} $$
hence:
$$ V = 6\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right) = \color{red}{2\pi-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}}.$$

[image]

Comment: I understand, but for this problem, I **must** use Spherical coordinates. I got the correct answer using Cartesian and Cylindrical as well, but I am having trouble using Spherical for this problem.

Comment: Also, the correct answer is $2\pi-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and not $4\pi-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: @bobtran12: if you are able to compute the volume with a simple technique, *cui prodest* to compute it also with a horrible one?

Comment: I agree, but it's a challenge question from my professor. Nonetheless, thank you!